# Refrescar un Jtable en tiempo real

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static Connection con = null;

public Connection ObtenerConeccion(){
    try {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cemagri";
        String UsuarioBD = "rootdos";
        String ContraseñaBD= "1234";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, UsuarioBD, ContraseñaBD);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la connecion! " + e);
    }
    return con;
}

private Connection con = new Conexion().ObtenerConeccion();

CallableStatement cb = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
 public ArrayList<Categorías> MostrarCategoriaLista() throws 
SQLException {
        ArrayList<Categorías> categoríases = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            cb = con.prepareCall("call Mostrar_Categorias");
            rs = cb.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Categorías c = new Categorías();
                c.setCat_Codigo(rs.getInt("cat_Codigo"));
                c.setCat_Nombre(rs.getString("cat_Nombre"));
                categoríases.add(c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta!! CATEGORIAS " + e);
        }finally{
            rs.close();
            cb.close();
            con.close();
        }
        return categoríases;
    }

   void MostrarDatosCategorias() {
    try {
    String titulos[] = {"ID", "CATEGORIAS"};
    DefaultTableModel df = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
    ControladorCategoria ctl = new ControladorCategoria();
    ArrayList<Categorías> PS = ctl.MostrarCategoriaLista();
    Iterator i = PS.iterator();
    String filas[] = new String[2];
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Categorías c;
        c = (Categorías) i.next();
        filas[0] = String.valueOf(c.getCat_Codigo());
        filas[1] = c.getCat_Nombre();
        df.addRow(filas);
        df.fireTableDataChanged();
    }      
    jTCategorias.setModel(df);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
};

 Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
@Overrible 
 Publico vos run(){
 While  (true){
 Try{
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  MostrarDatosCategoria();
  MostrarDatosMarcas();
  MostrarDatosSucursales(); 
   }cath (InterruptedException e){
  JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(Null,e);
  }
   }
   }
  };

 Public AdministracionDatos() {
initComponent();
MostrarDatosCategoria();
MostrarDatosMarcas();
MostrarDatosSucursales();
Thread hilo = new Thread(runnable);
hilo.start();
}
```

El error es

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConneCtionException: Connection is closed. controlador Categoria –

Este es mi código con las diferentes clases. La de conexión es una donde mando a llamar el método de la base de datos e instancio la conexión es otra, lo de más abajo es un JinternalFrame donde pongo el método.

Comment: Saludos. Te hizo falta indicar que ocurre; si falla (que error muestra, el error de la falla no el personalizado que pusieras),... algo que de una idea de que quieres corregir.

Comment: El error es que cada cierto tiempo digamos me tira un error de conexion de que se a cerrado y si le quito el con.close(); y los demas me dice too many coneccion que hay muchas coneciones y como eso que muestro en el codigo no es el unico interframe que ocupo asi me da esos errores y ya no se como solucionarlo. @RobertoLeOr

Comment: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConneCtionException: Connection is closed. controlador Categoria

Comment: ¿Por qué no editaste [la pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/475337/c%c3%b3mo-refrescar-un-jtable-autom%c3%a1ticamente) en lugar de formular una nueva?